# Create tmux session in seperate shells

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, tmux

I'd like to use tmux sessions to manage windows / panes in different shells. What I've noticed is that tmux will always use the shell from which it was first launched for all subsequent sessions regardless of the shell used for those.

I have two shells. Lets call them a and b

In the first shell I run:

```
tmux new -s a
```

In the second shell I run:

```
tmux new -s b
```

What I end up noticing is that the actual shell used by tmux session b is shell a. The environment variables are inherited correctly but the shell itself is not the one I expected it to be.

Any suggestions on how to get tmux to play nicely with multiple shells?

Answer (score 4):

You can create multiple tmux servers that each use a different shell.

```
$> SHELL=$(which zsh) && tmux -L zsh-tmux-socket new -s zsh-session
$> SHELL=$(which bash) && tmux -L bash-tmux-socket new -s bash-session
```

The [tmux man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html) states that the `[-L socket-name]` option allows a different socket name to be specified, **allowing several independent tmux servers to be run**.

I found that each new window created in each server session will be using the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable for that session.

This works for tmux 1.8, I don't know about earlier versions.